# iOS: Display last cells of table view after reload

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having table view with some sections and rows within it.
I want to set last cell from last section to be visible when view is loaded or reloaded.

I am using following code but my app gets crash at second line:

```
  NSIndexPath* lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[arrmChatLine count] inSection:[arrSectionTitles count]];
  [tablevMessageChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

Please suggest me solution or tell me what i am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: can you show the crsh report

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: section (5) beyond bounds (5).'

Comment: Please check whether your last section has correct number of rows?? It should have rows equal to [arrmChatLine count].

Comment: count of my arrays are: arrmChatLine: 17 arrSectionTitles: 5 But still it gets crash with this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (16) beyond bounds (5) for section (4).

Answer (score 0):

Check your numberOfRowsInSection delegate and numberOfSectionsInTableView so that they are set to desire value.

Reload TableView data before calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
// First figure out how many sections there are
int lastSectionIndex = [tablevMessageChat numberOfSections]-1;

// Then grab the number of rows in the last section
int lastRowIndex = [tablevMessageChat numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex]-1;

// Now just construct the index path
NSIndexPath * pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

// Make the last row visible
[tablevMessageChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:pathToLastRow atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[arrmChatLine count] - 1 inSection:[arrSectionTitles count] - 1];
```

your crash issue will be solved...